# TMDb API URL for upcoming movie

Tags: themoviedb-api

I am trying to get upcoming movie information from tmdb, and I used following URL:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/latest/?api_key=myKEY
```

and i am getting this message

> {"status_code":34,"status_message":"The resource you requested could be found."}

I know there is some mistake in URL. I read the [documentation](http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#reference/movies/movieupcoming)  and can not fix the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use URL without `/` at the end of resource path:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/latest?api_key=yourKey
```